Trouble with sizes and refresh rate display
I'm experiencing a problem with Ubuntu 24.04, even though I have set the native resolution of this PC and the global scale to 200% like on Windows... many applications that I open and use have microscopic text and icons... why ? I feel like uninstalling ubuntu, I'm having too many problems and finding little support.. Can anyone help me please?
Even the refresh rate remains unchanged at 60hz while the display actually reaches 120hz!
